# get deserialize data from serialize data jquery decodeURIComponent

Tags: jquery, serialization

```
var ser=$("input[name=\"convs[]\"]:checked").serialize();
var v=decodeURIComponent(ser);
console.log(v);
```

i get o/p is `convs[]=91&convs[]=89`

is it posssible to get 91 and 89 any idea

Answer (score 0):

use `serializeArray()` for this

http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/

and then iterate over the array:

```
var results = [];

$("input[name=\"convs[]\"]:checked").serializeArray().forEach( function( val ) {
   results.push( val.value );
});
```